# Angular 2 RC6 - dynamically load entryComponents

Tags: dynamic, angular

I made a popup component that dynamically loads a content component regardless of type. 
After RC4 it is impossible to inject components without adding them to the `entryComponents` list.

Is it possible to load components without specifying them in `entryComponents`?

Is it possible to load all components into `entryComponents` list dynamically and is it a good idea?

P.S. I don't see a point of them adding the `entryComponents` list

Comment: I think entryComponents is required for the offline template compiler. There should be a way if you use platform browser-dynamic. Don't know how though.

Comment: Sir, I respect your opinion, since you answered a couple of my previous questions. I lost hope and will resume my search for answers at a later point in time. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to add `entryComponents` to the popup component itself. You need to add `entryComponents` to the caller of the popup which probably injects the component to the popup

Comment: That was not the question. I made it work, but I don't want to write every component I want to get dynamically loaded into entryComponents list, so I was wondering if there was a way to bypass it.

Comment: I don't see such a bad thing to write components to that list, maybe it doesn't make too much sense, but you can see there all your dynamic components which it's a nice thing to have. Anyway there are perfomance concerns that's why **entrycomponents** is required : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-why-entry-components

Comment: I'm also wondering why adding dynamically added components to `entryComponents` is an issue. It allows you to still benefit from offline template compilation.

Comment: Well I guess I am the problem for being too lazy for not wanting to do something I was not required to do in previous RC-s.
I decided to create a code generator that will create a module out of files that are in a specific folder. 
Sorry for asking stupid questions.